# How to set random user id in get request

Tags: php, get

ecommerce website. in every product there is an option for view the product and seller who uploaded that product, to fetch the user and product id i have set a get request, but the problem is that the user id is displaying in url and if i set the user id to unique or rand then view product page is not getting the id because get id is random like 9827340741ghruwgh and and $_GET['user_id'] = 5

```
while ($row = fetch($connect)) {     THIS IS MAIN PRODUCT PAGE

  $seller_id  =  $row['seller_id'];


   echo "<a href='view_seller.php?us_id={$product_id}'>View</a>";
}

   $query = "SELECT * FROM user_seller WHERE seller_id = '".$_GET['us_id']."' LIMIT 1"; /// THIS IS VIEW_SELLER PAGE
```

THANKS

Comment: not clear what is the code that have the issue and why you need seller id to fetch seller. use product id and get the seller id from db

Comment: it was done by mistake seller_id is equal to the seller of the product and i want to fetch the seller and product id to show it to the buyer

Comment: still not clear can you edit your question and write in details what you need and what you have and check this because the naming is not convenient   $product_id  =  $row['seller_id'];

Comment: suppose you are the seller of a shirt, you posted your add on that website, now a buyer came and watch your add, he click on the add to view it, by clicking on the add he redirects to page, on that page there will be your add and your description, in order to fetch your add and seller info i have set a get request and in get request i wanna set the seller id to random for that buyer.

Comment: why you need to set it random, if you have ad for product when the customer click on the ad just put the product id in get parameters, no need to send seller id at all. what is the point of sending random seller id ?

Comment: I suspect the random id is more to do with user tracking than anything to do with the product. is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be eliminated with a little change to your code, instead of using links you can instead used forms and buttons. Then you can POST the data and its passed along in the background.

There is another option and as this is an Ecommerce platform it will have little impact because you will already want to use sessions, that is: store the data into the php session.

However, at this stage I feel that might be beyond your capability, not that I am discouraging or disparaging you in any way. So, my answer is to use form and POST it.

```
<form action="some_page" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="unique_name" value="<?php echo $id_here; ?>" class="btn-link">Go</button>
</form>

// inside the code access it as follows: $_POST['unique_name'];
```

One work or caution, you really must make sure that what you receive from the form/url params or any user input is exactly what you expect. IE you need to be validating and possibly sanitising your users information. If you always remember that all user supplied data is extremely high risk then you wont go far wrong.

DO NOT DO THIS:

```
SELECT something FROM somewhere WHERE something="$_GET['something']"
```

That select statement is using $_GET directly, instead use prepared statements, if you are unsure of those, look into PDO or myqli prepared statements for more information on how you can reduce the risk of such user data.

Comment: Thanks for your briefing, but it could not help me out, i have already tried the form and button method, but can you please explain me how to fetch product and user id from main product page through form method to single product page,

Comment: using the posted form you just access the post array. This website will be of help to you not just for this but for a lot of php basics. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm you can also try https://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp and https://www.php.net/ As you are just setting out, I would recommend learning PHP 7 which is the latest version. It may be helpful to have familiarity with the earlier versions but the latest is the new standard